# Fedora 25 VirtualBox installation

Tags: installation, virtualbox, fedora-25

When I installed VirtualBox 5.1 by instructions on Download page, everything finished successful.

When I tried run VirtualBox the error was showed:

```
VirtualBox: supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",) failed: libQt5X11Extras.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by install X11 extras:

```
dnf install qt5-qtx11extras.x86_64
```

After installation the library the error was shoved:

```
Qt FATAL: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This can be fixed by install X11 xkb common:

```
dnf install libxkbcommon-x11.x86_64
```

After those fixes everything works fine.

I repored it to Oracle [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16376)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced the same problem: installation of recent Fedora iso "26" with VirtualBox .
the truth is not all versions are supported ,the supported version are in range of 7-23 only as indicated in this site below:

[List of Supported iso](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes)